# go install 実行時に mkdir /home: read-only file system エラーになる

Tags: macos, go

```
go install github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0
```

上記のコマンドを実行すると

```
go install github.com/99designs/gqlgen: mkdir /home: read-only file system
```

というエラーが発生します。
エラー内容を調べてみるとMacのOSの設定によるエラーであるといった内容が出てきました。

しかし、他のプロジェクトで`go install`は成功しているため、OSによるものではないと考えています。
どなたか同じエラーに覚えのある方は、ご回答ください。

Answer (score 2):

> mkdir /home: read-only file system

MacOSのファイルシステムではルート直下「/」にディレクトリは作れません。
root権限でも作れません。

```
$ sudo mkdir /hogehoge
Password:********
mkdir: /hogehoge: Read-only file system
```

権限のある他のディレクトリを指定してください。

Answer (score 0):

どうやらGoの持つ環境変数のうち'GOBIN'のパスが間違っていたことによるエラーだったようです。